# Windows 10 uwp scenario c#

Tags: windows, uwp

I have currently a WP8.1 and a Win8.1 pair of apps laying in a solution.
I am trying to create a best-possible scenario in which:

1. I can keep the 8.1 and wp8.1 projects still buildable
2. I can add a uwp project(to the old solution) that uses the (linked?) files from the above projects

Is this even possible, or should I branch from the 8.1, create the uwp, create new UI, copy/paste the code?

Comment: It should be doable if the class libraries are PCLs, otherwise not sure.

Comment: I think it can be done. But you will have to use compiler directives to properly maintain the old code and add the new.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new project to the old solution and reference the 8.1 Universal App project. If you factored out enough code into the Shared project, you should be in for an easy migration.